# Isn't my HTOP weird on my Ubuntu server 12.04?

Tags: server, htop

It seems I have a lot of duplicate processes (apache), is it normal ?

This is the output of the **htop** command on my ubuntu server 12.04 :

[image]

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not weird.  Yes, it's normal.

Apache can use multi-processing modules (MPM) to handle concurrent requests (see [Apache MPM documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mpm.html)).  The default used in Ubuntu is `prefork`, which spawns several processes and allows each one to serve incoming requests.

If the server was receiving significant traffic, you would see even more processes spawned, but even without traffic there will be several spare processes waiting.